# How do I confirm if http post request has posted in flutter?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I have my app setup with mysql database running on xampp. When I try and implement http.post request, how do I know that my data has been posted to the server?

Comment: Just drop on the end of PHP script something like this echo json_encode("ok"), and process this in your flutter code.

Comment: I wonder if that's the only way to do it. For now I can do that but is it a concrete solution for commercial apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the statuscode for the response maybe?

usually if the post call works, you get back a response.statusCode == 200

Maybe try check for that on the device. Otherwise if you are talking about the code on your php, we need more informations.

eg on flutter:

```
 final response =
      await http.post('adress',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      body: json.encode({
        "parameter":"yourparameter",
      }));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
     final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      return parsed.map<ObjectResult>((json) => ObjectResult.fromJson(json)).toList();

  } else {
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
```

Comment: In my program, I am looping post for n times for n number of data to post them in different rows. How will response work in this case?